# Nothing happening and no errors with dispatch functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm managing my `React` application route with `react-router` and `react-router-redux`.

I setting router with following configuration:

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router'
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux'
import {routerReducer} from 'react-router-redux';
import {syncHistoryWithStore} from 'react-router-redux'

import Reducers from './reducers'; // contains all my reducers,

const store = createStore(combineReducers(
    {...Reducers, routerReducer}
));

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

const AppRoute = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path='login' components={PageLogin}/>
            <Route path='system' components={PageSystem}>
                <Route path="profile" component={PageProfile}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

export default AppRoute;
```

When I try dispatch any router function:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link, Route} from 'react-router';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {replace, push} from 'react-router-redux';

class SystemMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.logout   = this.logout.bind(this);
    }

    logout() {
        this.props.logout();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="system-menu">
                <li className={this.isActual("/system/profile")}>
                    <Link to="/system/profile">Profile</Link>
                </li>
                <li className={this.isActual("/system/unit")}>

                    <Link to="/system/unit">Units</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        router: state.router,
        actualPage: state.menu.actualPage
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        logout() {
            dispatch(push('/login'));
        }
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SystemMenu);
```

When I click que `Link` component, pages is changing, But when I click the `Logout` button to debug, is executing `dispatch(push('/login'));` line, but nothing has happening, and no occur any error in the console.

What I worse in the configuration?

---

I tried `console.log` the `logout` inside the `mapDispatchToProps` function, and returning `logout is not defined`

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    console.log(push, logout);

    return {
        logout() {
            dispatch(push('/login'));
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: if you `console.log` inside the `mapDispatchToProps` `logout()` function, do you see the log?

Comment: @DavinTryon I updated my question inserting the result of this test. (`logout is not defined`)

Comment: Why dont you use `browserHistory.push('/')`? You are syncing `browserHistory` with `store`, so everything will be okay

Comment: of course `console.log(logout)` will show `logout is not defined` because logout is not defined! @DavinTryon meant, put your `console.log` inside `logout() { ... }` function. Is it being called?

Comment: @free-soul if I try `console.log(this.props.logout);` is returning correct function, if I put some `console.log` before than logout `dispatch`, it will be executed too.

Comment: I meant to do this: `return { logout() { console.log('hello'); dispatch(push('/logon')); } }`  Just to make sure the logout is getting wired up correctly.

Comment: @DavinTryon yes, I have sure is executing `dispatch`

Answer (score 1):

`combineReducers` should take an object as the first argument, like this:

```
const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    routing: routerReducer
  })
)
```

You're giving it an Array instead.
I suspect the reason why `push` doesn't work is because the router reducer is not registered properly.

Comment: So sorry, this is my fail in post edition, in my real code is a object, I updated my question post.

Comment: No problem but still you're not properly registering the router reducer. It should be ```combineReducers({...Reducers, routing: routerReducer})```. They way you have it it's registering it under the ```routerReducer``` key

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this problem.

This problem is occurring because I has not using `react-router`redux` middleware, so when I dispatching, maybe is not updating browser URL by state.

Following my route configuration:

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router'
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import {routerReducer} from 'react-router-redux';
import {syncHistoryWithStore, routerMiddleware} from 'react-router-redux'

import Reducers from './reducers'; // contains all my reducers,

const middleware = [routerMiddleware(browserHistory)];

const store = createStore(combineReducers(Reducers), compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
));

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

const AppRoute = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path='login' components={PageLogin}/>
            <Route path='system' components={PageSystem}>
                <Route path="profile" component={PageProfile}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
);

export default AppRoute;
```